# How to determine which columns make p-value result in 0.0 in contingency table?

Tags: categorical-data, p-value, contingency-tables

I have a contingency table with which I am estimating if some categories are seasonal or not. I use p-value and Cramers V for that but for this question only p-value is important. The p-value resulted in 0.00 which means the data is seasonal. Now I want to find out which columns are the "most seasonal" so which columns contribute the most in the p-value resulting in 0.00. I have tried to iterate through all columns and extract a table with one column and calculate the p-value for every column, but it only results in p-value = 1 for every column/table so I guess that was the wrong way to do that.

Here is an example of the table I am talking about:

```
         Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 Cat4 Cat5 ... CatN
winter   129   239 45   123   400     231
spring   100  ...........................
summer   391  ...........................
fall      89  ...........................
```

Now I want to find out which Catx is the most seasonal of all.

Comment: You could look up “chi-square test with residuals”.

Comment: Thank you, @rolando2, I will look it up.